# Comparing 2 tables in rails 5

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 tables "existing_practices" & "latest_practices", both contain a column "practice_id"

What I want to do is compare latest_practices with the existing_practices to find which practices are on the latest_practices table that I don't have on my existing_practices (in other words I need to find the new practices)

Example:

```
existing_practices      latest_practices
------------------      ------------------
practice_id             practice_id
A123                    A123
B123                    B123
C123                    C123
                        D123
```

So given the 2 above tables I would need to identify that "D123" is a new practice.

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
existing_practices = ExistingPractice.select(:practice_id).all
latest_practices = LatestPractice.select(:practice_id).all

new_practices = latest_practices.to_a - existing_practices.to_a
```

I'm thinking the easiest way is to just write the raw sql but i want to do it the rails way (if there is one).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**pluck** used to fetch column value as array

```
new_practices = LatestPractice.pluck(:practice_id) - ExistingPractice.pluck(:practice_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of data the solution of plucking `practice_id` and subtracting them is poorly performing. Instead I suggest:

**Okish:**

```
LatestPractice.where.not(practice_id: ExistingPractice.all)
```

**better:**

```
LatestPractice.where.not("EXISTS(SELECT 1 from existing_practices where latest_practices.practice_id = existing_practices.practice_id)")
```

**much better:**

```
LatestPractice.where('practice_id NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT(practice_id) FROM existing_practices)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql directly for better performance.

```
new_practices_id = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT DISTINCT latest_practices.practice_id FROM latest_practices LEFT JOIN existing_practices ON latest_practices.practice_id =
existing_practices.practice_id WHERE existing_practices.practice_id IS NULL")
```

This will return an array of the `practice_id` that doesn't exist at the `existing_practices` table.

here is the fiddle example [company two columns or tables](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/755594/3)

you can do it like this with `pluck`

```
new_practices = LatestPractice.pluck(:practice_id) - ExistingPractice.pluck(:practice_id)
```

Comment: I say that's more like ruby way, but I wouldn't commit that code to production.

Comment: @radubogdan  he is asking in rails way only. by the way you are fetching table row but he asked id as array. first read question properly

Comment: @krishnar First of all the only question he has is `Can anyone help?`. Second of all he is only showing what he did, that doesn't mean you need to follow it. Third of all this solution does not perform well for M of records. Cheers.

Comment: @krishnar and he's trying to substract arrays of ActiveRecords, obviously he wants to end up with a relation or array of ActiveRecords :)

Comment: @radubogdan this is just a different answer no one says it is better, your solutions could much be better, but it doesn't mean it is the only solutions.